# Table not displaying as expected

Tags: html, css, html-table, display, css-tables

Why am I getting this kind of display when trying on add line to my table ? [image]

What I am trying to get is having the second Testssssssssss below the Commande column as expected. Below is my code:

```css
table {
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

#thead {
  background-color: #f8f4f4;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  color: #929292;
}

#tableBody {
  display: block;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead id="thead">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th scope="col">Commande</th>
      <th scope="col">Total</th>
      <th scope="col">Status</th>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Mode d'expédition</th>
      <th scope="col">Code promo</th>
      <th scope="col">Quantité</th>
      <th scope="col">Nom</th>
      <th scope="col">Voie</th>
      <th scope="col">Adresse</th>
      <th scope="col">Adresse 1</th>
      <th scope="col">Entreprise</th>
      <th scope="col">Ville</th>
      <th scope="col">Code Postal</th>
      <th scope="col">Pays</th>
      <th scope="col">Téléphone</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tableBody">
    <tr>
      <td scope="row">Testsssssssss</td>
      <td>Testsssssssss</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: the number of columns must match in each row - you need to either add more columns or use a `colspan`.  Also you can't change the `display`, otherwise it's no longer layed out as a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using table tag the display already set to table but then in your CSS you are overriding the display property to BLOCK, So the solution is simple please see the CSS below and also please add more data as number of headings.

```
table {
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

#thead {
  background-color: #f8f4f4;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  color: #929292;
}

/* #tableBody {
  display: block;
}This attribute is not needed  */ 

th {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I deleted that and the render adjusted partially. I still have two data below my Email column what makes all the cells shift by one column.. ? Newbie to HTML & CSS, please be kind ^^'

Comment: I didn't understand properly for me the code works fine, do you have anything else apart from this on the page? Please elaborate the issue

Comment: How can I upload an image on comments? It will be more easy to understand I guess.

Comment: Add it in your main question or any file upload website and give the link

Comment: Here is the link : https://ibb.co/Ny790xF, look at the email column, I have two values "-" and "#1001". "#1001" should be below Commande and 25.00 below Total.

Comment: do you have anthing else on the page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244701/discussion-between-sameer-and-anis).